# Integral $\cos\left(\ln\left(e^t+1\right)+at+b\right)dt$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral: 
$$\int \cos\left(\ln\left(e^t+1\right)+at+b\right)dt 
$$ with $$a, b \in \Re$$
I can solve this:
$$\int \cos\left(\ln\left(x\right)\right)dt 
$$ 
Defining: $u=\cos(\ln(x))$ and $v = \frac{1}{x}$. Then using the fomular two times:
$$\int udv=uv-\int vdu$$
I can get the solution 
$$\frac {1}{2}x\cos(\ln(x))+ \frac {1}{2}x\sin(\ln(x)) +C$$

I also found the orther topic in our website [The integral $\int\ln(x)\cos(1+(\ln(x))^2)\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696872/the-integral-int-lnx-cos1-lnx2-dx). But still have no idea with this.

I wonder is this non-integrable function ?!

Comment: Where this problem arise? For particular values of $a,b,t$ the integrand function is not even defined. Anyway *any* continuous function is integrable over closed intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, but I won't bet a penny on the fact that $(e^t+at+b)^i$ has a primitive which can be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: I typed wrong equation. But i don't know how to rewrite my question. My question is about this: $\int cos\left(ln\left(e^t+1\right)+at+b\right)dt$

Comment: I derived this integration from the dynamic and kinematic equation of autonomous underwater vehicle (AUV) when I consider a turning motion of AUV. This is X coordinate.

Comment: I tried both wxmaxima and sympy. Both cannot integrate it symbolically (of course, its antiderivative still exists since it is continuous).

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?